# Sample size Red flags for a data set I was asked to analyze, please help

Tags: sample-size, small-sample, generalization

I am working in polishing up work an undergraduate class did and the data set is raising a lot of red flags for me. Like to the point that if these concerns I have aren’t resolved by either redoing the sampling or explaining why my concerns aren’t valid, I’m going to walk away from the project. But before making that ultimatum, I want to make sure I’m not missing anything.

1. The survey itself has 135 responses. Problem is that the group actually being studied only had 17 respondents total with some questions being much lower. There are basically two binary independent variable that define 4 groups. Student: y vs no, veteran: y vs no. The group that we care about is student veterans which the n=17.veteran non-students: n=5, Non-veteran students: n=46, non-v, non-s: n= 47 (combined total: n=115. Not everyone answered both questions).
2. The sampling is non-randomized. Even if I were convinced that n=17 wasn’t too small for generalization to a larger population, it’s not Randomized anyway (most if not all responses came from snowball sampling). The other source was a link included on in a veteran center monthly email (double self-selection bias given how de veteran’s actually read it).
3. Last issue: much of the data is ordinal data requiring non parametric analysis. While not normally a major issue, but given the other issues,it is just one more thing that undermines the validity of the data analysis.
4. What is an acceptable margin of error for sample mean? Unlike margin of error for proportions, the moe for means isn’t a percentage. I’m guessing I can just divide that by the mean to get percentage, but I cannot find anything online specifying what’s acceptable margin of error for means.

So am I wrong in thinking a non-random sample of 17 prevents any meaningful generalization of data for research/policy interests.

Comment: For 4) The uncertainty estimation of the estimated mean is given by the standard error.

Answer (score 1):

For sample size, well, as you surely know, a small sample will lead to imprecise estimates of any parameter. How imprecise and estimate can you tolerate?

For nonrandomness - if you don't have a random sample, there may be problems with inference (or generalization) regardless of sample size. In 1936 the Literary Digest did a poll on the presidential election and, based on millions of responses, confidently predicted that Alf Landon would beat FDR in a landslide. In reality, FDR won one of the biggest landslides of any presidential election.

The key thing there is how biased the sample is, and how that might affect your conclusions.

Still, many, many studies can't have random selection. I don't think I've ever worked on a data set that was truly a random selection from a well-defined population. These studies can still be valuable.

For ordinal data I am not sure why you say that ordinal data requires "nonparametric" statistics. Some methods for ordinal data are quite parametric.

As to what is an acceptable MOE for a mean, the reason you can't find literature on it is that you have to decide (perhaps in consultation with substance matter experts) on what is acceptable or not. It depends entirely on the situation. Sometimes you need a very precise estimate, other times a WAG (wild ass guess) will do.